# Help with a very hard integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$
\int^{\infty}_{1} \Bigl(\,\Bigl|3\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}}+x\Bigr|-\Bigl|3\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}}-x\Bigr|\,\Bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x=
\int^{\infty}_{1} \Bigl(3\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}}+x-\Bigl|3\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}}-x\Bigr|\,\Bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I literally have no idea on how to do this, perhaps through complex analysis or polar coordinates(?). Also I only want an exact answer.

Thanks!

Edit:
Thanks to metamorphy for pointing out that I don't need the first absolute value.

Comment: You want the nature or the value ?

Comment: You can remove the second absolute value as well, as the inside is always negative, multiply by a negative sign after removing and simplify the expression.

Comment: @haman_Abdallah What do you mean by "nature"?

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! I am sorry : this is not a very hard integral ! It is just a pure nightmare. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is proving $3\exp -\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}<x$ for all $x\ge 1$. (Judging by [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=plot+3*exp(-x%5E2%2F(x-1)%5E0.5)-x+from+1+to+10) graph, you just need to check its derivative is negative.) So your integral is $$\int_1^\infty \left(3\exp -\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}+x+3\exp -\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}}-x\right)dx=6\int_1^\infty\exp -\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x-1}} dx.$$[However](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=integrate+exp(-x%5E2%2F(x-1)%5E0.5)+from+1+to+infinity), there doesn't seem to be a non-numerical method for this.